# How to unhide Intel SSD

Tags: intel, solid-state-drive

I have bought a new Intel SSD 120GB. I wanted to use it as my operating system drive. However, I cannot find it in my computer. Even I went to Disk Management to assign new letter for it, it disappeared every time when I rebooted. I tried to use diskpart command to show my disk. It still automatically hided when I restart the computer. Is there anyone can tell me how to show it and make it as my operating system drive. Cheers.

[image]

This picture shows the disk is hidden

Comment: This question would be more appropriate on http://superuser.com/ Note: There may already be a similar question there so search for a duplicate before posting a question

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to cmd
2. type in "diskpart"
3. type "list volume"
4. select volume/harddrive
5. choose drive by typing "select volume x" (x is an assigned number)
6. type "assign"
7. exit diskpart and reboot if needed

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I did what you said but when I reboot, the disk still disappear. I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: @Rui read my comment above, the question is off topic here on stack overflow but over on superuser.com it is right on topic, so ask there

Comment: Thank your for that. I will post question there.